# Oracle SQL query performance in where clause

Tags: sql, oracle, performance

I have a query (see below). When I put the below line in the where clause, it runs very slow, when I leave it out it runs very quick, is there anyway I can fool the optimizer which will enable me to leave this is in the where clause but have the same performance. I'm running in Oracle 11g.

**AND uh.prod_exploitation_cre_surr_id   IS NOT NULL**

```
   SELECT   uh.prod_exploitation_cre_surr_id
           , uh.rowid as uh_row_id
            , uh.surr_id uh_surr_id
            , uh.right_type
            , uh.prod_received_with_cre_surr_id
            , eap_bro.eap_broadcaster_name
            , eap_bro.eap_broadcaster_station_id
            , eap_bro.eap_production_number
    FROM         
        (SELECT eap.eap_broadcaster_station_id, eap.eap_production_number, eap.eap_broadcaster_name, bro.tp_surr_id
         FROM 
            (SELECT * from ETL_ACQUIRED_PRODUCTIONS where eap_date_added is null) eap
        JOIN broadcasters           bro ON eap.eap_broadcaster_station_id  = bro.station_id) eap_bro
    JOIN usage_headers          uh ON uh.bro_broadcast_by_tp_surr_id   = eap_bro.tp_surr_id  
    WHERE eap_bro.eap_production_number = uh.production_number 
    AND NVL (uh.dn_uls_usage_status, '3')  NOT IN ('9', '11')  
    AND uh.right_type    IN ('B', 'M')  
    AND uh.prod_exploitation_cre_surr_id   IS NOT NULL  -- line that makes it run slow
    AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1                                                                  
                    FROM production_usage_components puc
                    WHERE puc.uh_surr_id = UH.SURR_ID
                    AND PUC.DISTRIBUTION_STATUS IS NOT NULL);
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: Is prod_exploitation_cre_surr_id  primary key or any index on it? If not try to put a index on it.

Comment: And what does the optimizer say when you run execution plan for this query.

Comment: @FreeMan - methinks if that column was PK then the optimizer would automatically ignore the check for "IS NOT NULL" - it wouldn't even appear in the execution plan (since a PK can't be NULL). So no, it is very unlikely that that column is PK.

Comment: you're right.So what about any index on it?

Comment: Are you sure it is really "running fast" without that condition?  I.e., please confirm you didn't run it and immediately get a screen full of rows with NULL `prod_exploitaition_cre_surr_id`s.  Getting the 1st page of results quickly does not mean the query "runs fast".  Until you scroll down to the last row, you really don't know how fast it ran.